# How can I make my PySimpleGui window usage less monolithic?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have been using pysimplegui to make a somewhat large program, and I'm wondering if there is a better design pattern for handling the window.

Currently I make the window at the beginning as an empty global variable, and set it later on during the startup of my program with the layout.

```
WINDOW=None

def setup()

  global WINDOW

  ...

  WINDOW = psg.Window("Name", layout)
```

The reason why I'm using a global system is the program is very asynchronous, with almost every part of my program using the window but only specific parts actually update it (done by disabling most elements)

Is there a better design pattern for the pysimplegui code, considering that the code is quite monolithic?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how about less monolithic ?

Example to show how I do it.

[image]

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def hide(key, settings):

    setting = not settings[key]
    settings[key] = setting
    window[key].update(visible=setting)

def layout(settings):

    selection1 = [
        [sg.Text("Select item1:")]] + [
        [sg.Checkbox(f"Item {j*3+i+1}")
            for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)
    ]

    selection2 = [
        [sg.Text("Select item2:")]] + [
        [sg.Checkbox(f"Item {j*3+i+1}")
            for i in range(4)] for j in range(2)
    ]

    form = [
        [sg.Text('Selection'), sg.Button("Item 1"), sg.Button("Item 2")],
        [sg.pin(sg.Column(selection1, visible=settings['Col 1'], key='Col 1'), shrink=False)],
        [sg.pin(sg.Column(selection2, visible=settings['Col 2'], key='Col 2'), shrink=False)],
    ]

    return form

settings = {'Col 1':True, 'Col 2':False}

sg.theme('DarkBlue')
window = sg.Window('Title', layout(settings), size=(250, 260),
    use_default_focus=False, finalize=True)

for key, element in window.AllKeysDict.items():  # remove dash box from elements
    element.Widget.configure(takefocus=0)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event in ("Item 1", "Item 2"):
        key = 'Col 1' if event == 'Item 1' else 'Col 2'
        hide(key, settings)

window.close()
```